# Mongodb c# filter using and or operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, linq, filter

I have json documents in `mongodb`

**Sample**

```
{
 "SchemaName": "Intelligence",
 "SchemaDescription": "WindPower",
 "SchemaType": "WindPower",
 "SchemaTypeId": 1,
 "SchemaData": {
  "ProjectId": 1,
  "LastUpdated": "2016-07-02T19:27:28.000+0000",
  "ProjectName": "Zhonghuashan II",
  "Capacity": 49.0,
  "Technology": "Onshore",
   "Country":{
          "CountryId":1,
          "CountryName":"UnitedKingdom",
          "CountryCode":"UK"
    }
 }
}
```

Now I am filtering data on basis on search criteria

```
var filter = Builders<Schema>.Filter.Or(
                Builders<Schema>.Filter.Where(p => p.SchemaData.ProjectName.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteria.ProjectName.ToLower())),
                Builders<Schema>.Filter.Where(p => p.SchemaData.Technology.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteria.Technology.ToLower())),
                Builders<Schema>.Filter.Where(p => p.SchemaData.Country.CountryName.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteria.Country.ToLower()))
            );
            var list = await collectionHandler.ReadOnly<Schema>().FindSync(filter).ToListAsync();
            return list;
```

I need to add condition

1. `searchCriteria.ProjectName ="" || searchCriteria.Technology="" || searchCriteria.Country = "" = return all records`
2. `searchCriteria.ProjectName ="abc" and searchCriteria.Technology="xyz" || searchCriteria.Country = "" = return matched records`
3. `searchCriteria.ProjectName ="abc" and searchCriteria.Technology="xyz" and searchCriteria.Country = "pqr" = return matched records`
4. `searchCriteria.ProjectName ="" || searchCriteria.Technology="xyz" and searchCriteria.Country = "pqr" = return matched records`
5. `searchCriteria.Technology="" ="abc" || searchCriteria.Technology="xyz" and searchCriteria.Country = "pqr" = return matched records`

say any property of search criteria can have combination of and and or with other property of search criteria

Answer (score 0):

For me I'm comfortable with directly passing filters as string:

```
    FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = @"{ ""Prop"": { $Or: [{ $and: [...] },{ $and: [...] }] } }";
    var lst = collection.Find(filter);
```

You can review the documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/or/

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

Took as base this answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54305932/how-to-lookup-with-pipeline-let-parameters-in-c-sharp-mongodb-driver-2-7-2)

```
        var idFilter = new BsonDocument { { "_id", new BsonDocument { { "$regex", codeRegex }, { "$options", "i" } } } };
        var nameFilter = new BsonDocument { { "Name", new BsonDocument { { "$regex", codeRegex }, { "$options", "i" } } } };

        var filter = new BsonDocument("$or", new BsonArray { idFilter, nameFilter });

        var query = _collection.Find(filter)                
            .SortBy(c=>c.Id);
        return query.ToList();
```